# Ruby ROXML - how to get an array to render its xml?

Tags: xml, ruby

I'm trying to create a Messages object that inherits Array. The messages will gather a group of Message objects. I'm trying to create an xml output with ROXML that looks like this:

```
<messages>
    <message>
        <type></type>
        <code></code>
        <body></body>
    </message>
    ...
</messages>
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the message objects in the Messages object to display in the xml. Here is the code I've been working with:

```
require 'roxml'

class Message
  include ROXML

  xml_accessor :type
  xml_accessor :code
  xml_accessor :body
end

class Messages < Array
  include ROXML

  # I think this is the problem - but how do I tell ROXML that
  # the messages are in this instance of array?
  xml_accessor :messages, :as => [Message]

  def add(message)
    self << message
  end

end


message = Message.new
message.type = "error"
message.code = "1234"
message.body = "This is a test message."

messages = Messages.new
messages.add message

puts messages.length
puts messages.to_xml
```

This outputs:

```
1
<messages/>
```

So, the message object I added to messages isn't getting displayed. Anyone have any ideas? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible. You are somehow trying to get access to the internal state of the `Array` class, which is not only impossible because on most implementations those internals are hidden away in the C/C++/Java/.NET/Objective-C/ABAP runtime but also quite simply a bad idea and bad object-oriented design.

The thing is, `Messages` is really not an `Array`, therefore it shouldn't inherit from `Array`. Tell me: are you really 100% sure that your `Messages` class is able to faithfully fulfill the contracts of *all* 81 methods on `Array`? And what do `assoc`, `rassoc`, `rindex` and `transpose` even *mean*, when applied to `Messages`?

You'd be much better off using delegation instead of inheritance here. This gives you a nice named entity that you can pass to `xml_accessor`:

```
require 'forwardable'
require 'roxml'

class Messages
  extend Forwardable
  include ROXML

  class << self; alias_method :[], :new end

  xml_reader :messages, :as => [Message]

  def initialize(*messages) @messages = messages end

  def_delegators :messages, :length, :<<
end
```

Note: I also changed a couple of other things here. For example, I personally believe that an object should be valid and usable after it is constructed. In your version of the code, a `Message` is basically invalid after it is constructed and only becomes valid after you call the `type=`, `code=` and `body=` setters:

```
class Message
  include ROXML

  class << self; alias_method :[], :new end

  xml_reader :type, :body
  xml_reader :code, :as => Integer

  def initialize(type=nil, code=nil, body=nil)
    @type, @code, @body = case opts = type
    when Hash
      opts[:type], opts[:code], opts[:body]
    else
      type, code, body
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a slightly expanded usage example:

```
msgs = Messages[Message['error', 1234, 'This is a test message.'], Message[]]

msgs << Message[
  type: 'warning', 
  code: 4815162342, 
  body: 'This is another test message.'
]

puts msgs.to_xml
# => <messages>
# =>   <message>
# =>     <type>error</type>
# =>     <body>This is a test message.</body>
# =>     <code>1234</code>
# =>   </message>
# =>   <message/>
# =>   <message>
# =>     <type>warning</type>
# =>     <body>This is another test message.</body>
# =>     <code>4815162342</code>
# =>   </message>
# => </messages>
```

Comment: Very good explanation. I now agree that messages shouldn't be inheriting from Array... I guess I thought it should because messages would be a collection. Thanks for the help.