# Calling to_xml on an Array of ROXML objects results in an empty collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have a ROXML object that looks like:

```
class Activity
  include ROXML
  xml_accessor :id
end
```

If I have an array of these objects and call .to_xml on the array, I receive an empty xml collection:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<activities type=\"array\">\n</activities>\n"
```

Any idea why or how to fix this?

I'm running Rails 2.3.5 with the newest version of ROXML.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [Ruby ROXML - how to get an array to render its xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844106/ruby-roxml-how-to-get-an-array-to-render-its-xml). Look there for details.

It seems that it is not possible to convert an array using ROXML. One way to solve this is to define new class for collection:

```
class Activities
  include ROXML
  def initialize(activities) 
    @activities = activities 
  end
  xml_reader :activities, :as => [Activity]
end
```

And use:

```
Activities.new(activities).to_xml
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll try that out.  Cheers.